# Using collections.Counter to count emojis with different colors

Tags: python, unicode, counter, emoji

I would like to use the collections.Counter class to count emojis in a string. It generally works fine, however, when I introduce colored emojis the color component of the emoji is separated from the emoji like so:

```
>>> import collections
>>> emoji_string = ""
>>> emoji_counter = collections.Counter(emoji_string)
>>> emoji_counter.most_common()
[('', 5), ('', 1), ('', 1), ('', 1), ('', 1), ('', 1)]
```

How can I make the most_common() function return something like this instead:

```
[('', 1), ('', 1), ('', 1), ('', 1), ('', 1)]
```

I'm using Python 3.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to split your string into separate clusters. Each of your emoji is really *two codepoints*; the emoji and a EMOJI MODIFIER FITZPATRICK TYPE X codepoint:

```
>>> print(emoji_string[0])

>>> print(emoji_string[1])

>>> print(emoji_string[:2])

>>> print(ascii(emoji_string[:2]))
'\U0001f44c\U0001f3fb'
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(emoji_string[1])
'EMOJI MODIFIER FITZPATRICK TYPE-1-2'
```

You could use a regular expression to keep those with the preceding emoji:

```
import re

char_with_modifier = re.compile(r'(.[\U0001f3fb-\U0001f3ff]?)')
split_emoji = char_with_modifier.findall(emoji_string)
```

and count the result.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> emoji_string = ""
>>> char_with_modifier = re.compile(r'(.[\U0001f3fb-\U0001f3ff]?)')
>>> Counter(char_with_modifier.findall(emoji_string))
Counter({'': 1, '': 1, '': 1, '': 1, '': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I tweaked the regex a bit because I'd like it to find regular emojis as well and not just the colored ones (.(?:[\U0001f3fb-\U0001f3ff])?)

Answer (score 0):

```
import regex
from collections import Counter
emoji_string = ""
data = regex.findall(r'\X',emoji_string)
print(Counter(data))
```

Expected output

```
Counter({'': 1, '': 1, '': 1, '': 1, '': 1})
```