# Extract all Emojis from string and ignore Fitzpatrick modifiers (skin tones etc.) in Python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, emoji

I recently had a problem where I needed to extract all Emojis in a string to count the occurrence of specific Emojis. The [Emoji python package](https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji) let me extract all Emojis, but I always got specific modifiers such as Skin tones extracted as separate Emojis. I wanted to ignore Skin tones and other Fitzpatrick modifiers [Variant Selectors](https://codepoints.net/variation_selectors) (see [this page for types](https://emojipedia.org/modifiers/) and [background on Fitzpatrick from Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitzpatrick_scale)). The following code will result in Fitzpatrick modifiers selected as separate emojis (which is not what I need):

```py
import emoji
def extract_emojis(str):
  return list(c for c in str if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI)
```

Example: this emoji `❤️` is actually composed of two parts, a heart (Unicode Codepoint: `U+2764`) and a modifier for red (Unicode Codepoint: `U+fe0f`). `print(repr('❤️'))` results in: [\u2764\ufe0f](http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/40/symbols/red-heart) - two separate unicodes but only one emoji. The second code point alone does not make sense on its own, yet it is returned as a separate emoji in the list from `return list(c for c in str if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI)`.

Comment: I removed this part. I already had the answer when writing the question, I just thought that the answer might be interesting to other people, too.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, this makes total sense! I hope this post is now according to the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution to ignore Skin tones and other modifiers and treat all these emoji variations as one emoji. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43852859/4556479) from Martijn Pieters here helped writing the following solution to my problem:

```py
import emoji
import unicodedata

def checkEmojiType(strEmo):
    if unicodedata.name(strEmo).startswith("EMOJI MODIFIER"):
        return False
    else:
        return True
def extract_emojis(str):
    return list(c for c in str if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI and checkEmojiType(c))
```

[edit]
However..At the moment, Zero-Width Joiners (see comment below) seem not supported by the solution above. You can test it yourself with the following code:

```
n = '‍⚕️' #copy the medical emoji with zero-width joiner (http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-zwj-sequences.html). This should only fall back to a double-emoji if not otherwise available
#extract all emojis with the function from above
nlist = def_functions.extract_emojis(n)
for xstr in nlist:
    #print codepoints
    print('Emoji Extract: U+%04x' % ord(xstr))
for _c in n:
    #print all Unicode Codepoints directly
    print('Each Codepoint: U+%04x' % ord(_c))
```

This is the output:

```
EmojiExtract: U+1f468
EmojiExtract: U+2695
Each Codepoint: U+1f468
Each Codepoint: U+200d
Each Codepoint: U+2695
Each Codepoint: U+fe0f
```

Emoji Extract didn't join the two Emojis (which would be somehow expected).

Comment: Please note that the above answer is not complete (I just realized). There are other forms of Emoji-Combinations, known apparently as [Emoji ZWJ Sequences](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-zwj-sequences/) that are equally constructed from several Unicode-Codepoints.. I haven't found a solution to remove these yet. [here are some examples](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-zwj-sequences.html)

Comment: `if x: False else: True` could simply be `not x`.